# Change passwords in an LDIF file using ldapmodify command

Tags: ldap

I have a LDIF file with a test user and I would like to change the password.

I used the ldapmodify command:

```
ldapmodify -h localhost  -D uid=testuser,ou=users,dc=mytest,dc=org -w <password> <<!
dn: uid=testuser,ou=users,dc=mytest,dc=org
changetype: modify
replace: userPassword
userPassword: myNewPassword
!
modifying entry "uid=testuser,ou=users,dc=mytest,dc=org"
```

It's looks like working

But when I open my file.ldif, the password has don't change and ldapsearch command don't work.

```
ldapsearch -x -h localhost -D uid=testuser,ou=users,dc=mytest,dc=org -w myNewPassword -b uid=testuser,ou=users,dc=mytest,dc=org
ldap_bind: Invalid credentials (49)
```

Thank you for the help

Comment: Provide which server implementation you are using this against. Do you have proper permissions?

Comment: Finaly, the password has been change, I don't know what happen...